# Lenstra's elliptic curve factorization problems

Tags: python, elliptic-curve, prime-factoring

I'm trying to use [Hendrik Lenstra's elliptic curve factoring method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic_curve_factorization) to factor small (less than 40 bits) composite integers.

```
import math 
from fractions import gcd
import random 

def lenstra_elliptic_curve_factor(N):
     """ Lenstra's elliptic curve factoring method """

    if N <=0:
    raise Exception("Integer %s must be possitive " % N) 

    # Can't be 1 and can't factor a prime! 
    if 1 <= N <= 2 or is_probable_prime(N):
        return [N]

    # random point in the plain (values less than N)
    x0, y0 = random.randrange(1, N), random.randrange(1, N)

    factors = list()
    bound = int(math.sqrt(N))

    for a in xrange(2,N):
        # Build curve out of random points
        b = y0**2 - x0**3 - a*x0

        # Check curve is not singular 
        if 4*a**3 - 27*b**2 ==0:
            continue

        # Initially double point 
        s = 3*x0**2 + a
        (x,y) = (s**2 - 2*x0, s*((s**2 - 2*x0) - x0) - y0)

    # Keep adding points until gcd(x-x0,N) != 1
    for k in xrange(2,bound):
        for i in xrange(0,math.factorial(k)):
            d = gcd(x- x0,N)
            if d != 1:
                return lenstra_elliptic_curve_factor(int(d)) + lenstra_elliptic_curve_factor(int(N/d))
            else:
                # Point doubling arithmetic 
                s = (y - y0) * modInv(x - x0,N)
                x = s**2 - x - x0  
                y = - y + s * (s**2 - x - x0 - x)
```

Where `is_probably_prime()` is the [Miller-Rabin test](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test#Python) with number of trials set to 20. It seems that for some composite numbers, for example 4, it doesn't find non-trivial `gcd(x-x0)`, instead the algorithm goes all the way through and returns nothing. So when the algorithm tries to factor a larger number which 4 divides, like 12 for example, `return lenstra_elliptic_curve_factor(int(d)) + lenstra_elliptic_curve_factor(int(N/d))` adds a "NoneType" to a list. For example

```
for x in xrange(0,3241):
    print x, lenstra_elliptic_curve_factor(x)
```

I get

```
0 [0]
1 [1]
2 [2]
3 [3]
4 None
5 [5]
6 None
7 [7]
8 None
9 [3, 3]
10 [2, 5]
11 [11]
12

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/AVcrypto/util.py", line 160, in <module>
     print x, lenstra_elliptic_curve_factor(x) 
File "/Users/Kevin/gd/proj/curr/honproj/AVcrypto/util.py", line 104, in lenstra_elliptic_curve_factor
     return lenstra_elliptic_curve_factor(int(d)) + lenstra_elliptic_curve_factor(int(N/d))
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list
```

I've tried increasing the number of curves tested to `N**10` but it seems to have the same result. I'm just wondering if anyone has any experience with this algorithm, specifically where certain numbers seem to avoid the trial process for an incredibly long time.

Comment: Just gonna say it. You might have better luck at math.stackexchange.com with this question (or even compsci).

Comment: Thanks I'll give compsci a try too!

Answer (score 2):

Lenstra's algorithm assumes that the number being factored is co-prime to 6 (that is, has no factors of 2 or 3). Trying to factor 4 will not work. A more realistic test is to factor 13290059.

I assume you know that ECM is vast overkill for 40-bit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, thanks!

Decided to implement from scratch my own version of ECM method. It has quite small and cleanly programmed code, so hope it will be useful to you to figure out what to do to improve your code.

Regarding your code. One main drawback is that you didn't create many curves, you used only one curve. Classical ECM generates Many curves with growing bound. Second smaller drawback that you used factorial as curve multiplier, much more faster would be to use product of small powers of small primes, it is enough instead of factorial.

**Very important** drawback in your code is that you do point addition to itself Factorial times. If you read article [Elliptic Curve Multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication) you'll see that for multiplication it is enough to do Binary Exponentiation, same as it is done for regular numbers, as described in [Right-to-Left Binary Exponentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method). This kind of exponentiation is MUCH MUCH MORE faster than your current, especially when factorial gets bigger. Now you do `O(Factorial)` additions, while you can do just `O(Log2(Factorial))`, much less operations.

Also you say that main problem with your code that it skips very tiny factors like 4. It may happen so because ECM is meant for much more bigger numbers. And it may have some special behaviour for several tiny numbers like 4. Regular practice in this case is to use [Trial Division Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) to remove all factors smaller lets say 16 bits. For all numbers bigger 16 bits ECM will work for sure.

I implemented all (even small) sub-algorithms totally from scratch, didn't use any library function even [math.gcd()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd). Out of library functions only used [math.sqrt()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sqrt), and [random.randrange()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange).

I used following sub-algorithms in my code: [Trial Division Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division), [Fermat Probability Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test), [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) (prime numbers generator), [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) (computing Greatest Common Divisor, GCD), [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) (GCD with Bezu coefficients), [Modular Multiplicative Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse), [Right-to-Left Binary Exponentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) (for elliptic point multiplication), [Elliptic Curve Arithmetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication) (point addition and multiplication), [Lenstra Elliptic Curve Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization).

My algorithm according to [ECM in Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization) is as following:

1. Check if number is smaller than 2^16, then factor it through [Trial Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) method. Return result.
2. Check if number is probably prime with high condifence, for that I use [Fermat Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test) with 32 trials. To overcome Carmichael numbers you may use [Miller Rabin Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) instead. If number is primes return it as only factor.
3. Generate curve parameters `A, X, Y` randomly and derive `B` from curve equation `Y^2 = X^3 + AX + B (mod N)`. Check if curve is OK, value `4 * A ** 3 - 27 * B ** 2` should be non-zero.
4. Generate small primes through [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), primes below our Bound. Each prime raise to some small power, this raised prime would be called K. I do raising into power while it is smaller than some Bound2, which is `Sqrt(Bound)` in my case.
5. Compute elliptic point multiplication `P = k * P`, where K taken from previous step and P is (X, Y). Compute according [to Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication).
6. Point multiplication uses [Modular Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse), which computes `GCD(SomeValue, N)` according [to Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). If this GCD is not 1, then it gives non-1 factor of N, hence in this case I through an Exception and return this factor from ECM factorization algorithm.
7. If all primes till Bound were multiplied and gave no factor then re-run ECM factorization algorithm (`1.-6.` above) again with another random curve and bigger Bound. In my code I take new bound by adding 256 to old bound.

As an example in following code I factorize 72-bit number just within 0.1-5 seconds of run, very fast! Re-run code many times to see factorizing of different example numbers. If it takes too much time then break program and re-run it to randomly roll-out another simpler number.

Example of console output for 96-bit (29 digit) random number:

```
N: 41498298392926620982104401176
Curve    0,  bound 2^  8.00
Factor ECM: 8
Factors TrialDiv: [2, 2, 2]
Curve    1,  bound 2^  9.00
Factor ECM: 13
Curve    2,  bound 2^  9.58
Factor ECM: 11
Curve    3,  bound 2^ 10.00
Curve    4,  bound 2^ 10.32
Factor ECM: 45061
Curve    5,  bound 2^ 10.58
Curve    6,  bound 2^ 10.81
Curve    7,  bound 2^ 11.00
Factor ECM: 2338703
41498298392926620982104401176 : [2, 2, 2, 11, 13, 45061, 2338703, 344213870325863]
Time 0.214 sec
```

Full code below:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVdrb9pIFP3Or5hVtYuddUiAqq2iJhJp09VKWyvqRitQxFoGD2aEGbvjITVb9bdnz/X71UeKBMbj@77nPhwd9TaU01eRenz0@Ia9c9c6VDdv3hu2xU4stgoP0mOXbMxev2avLCbWB/XAcXBuXgwYPs/YVusovjg743L0SexExD3hjkLln9Hd2V9cxlq5Dg8CEWmxPk0FOJtUj/jP1SKUqSCxj0Kl2d7VW4spV3rhPj2vrLpTwg3eigcjyXX/iP6UyfHEg4gLTfTZxPDhflndh4p5TEjS7HNjYrGE/c7GNUWpjRsQneB7xZLmE/qsFHd3jdNPWxFwSPoVLJeIWZdnE4/cKOLSMzyz8zBhZ2eXzBvU1CfsFySjKaeSkVQyFNcHJVmMmHLP2MRmFUyuEOTbD7eGtJim8FAsppMnBDUT4URK7N1A6KOjeawbsRRVLDMV3UhG4Scjy/OILkJqCrtkp2xiZtcxLmaPwzX/3kE0bzt9pw68dPcPLm9hJ48NROgJPv4tOHAabpwb5eow1lsueVxyr0PANRaaSuE@NWIJYEBDIwpRA1HkIcF7FH9UOrUGEJua3ciUwu@jZdfzdSi1kAfexEAz5hGMiSyyx2KR2Sej0CCW8KAMWL/hzcDlRspQf8fQo@CBx6IqE2/eGi5ayhOScHNYB8LjrnTcwEe/0Nv9oFlcK8JHq7BICbxaWcxF6a3a8HBLi25@xqREIx7cc75lmwrRwyxUH76whFRYBOfzlvWqx3riNT6C3wQnhKB37UPPSEU2e0QhPiZNqJePyHrc9pb4iBACQAK6E@aaaCx5XCgMaX3cohzrUEk7/wTSm7BNj820N5ak@whkUcs1wlTTMZCd1OlyIOH46jJX99U6BxFMrrD0PvT@lA@UO/mE3IHrELjK2R8CLaJArDF@UORCPnBVayNAzSWrZoVvUYQ1fCzwIs16T/Z7WpRyRczZP25w4DdKhcpwu60Z2JQVFNczzzNmFru22PzcYgt850DMYvwUbOZD1smGbBQidw1naxMQhs/PaSrNxwztFwrpZtHy4xl7Gx5WQbPZBAiFYUyBJEg4OWETwGFm4jbPygR/yX7bNOGjPWjONPAGGRc6fSqjS3XMqZgBDacsMfGzaNFxNN22sYhhj6WLcc5eWjink/kPmZgaMB//nI15qhOLHWuZfn8IikwjwRbb/QSEeRKFkmMSpFl99kH4W32qw9OAb7SzEtJVR2fPsdxVAXHjmGPD2lG5oatXq8qOnQLA5e01rLpewDuyrlXVu56GBSTt2G99Q5oEUNnUsZ16nKlodrNSbZ08O@xngCNXdbvzYJdWU7BtnmjaZusrY7k6FKtuUu252fV3ZmQLr1nbePM/aeer@pArpNFIH50wSGWzYirQeUlQrz@bvc4VjV@Y7Z0OGltrr222wx5wSatdmtBu9LGeoXUPMykxK@RcDC2Ixzc4xNt8@Dcl5wHaxL1WV/uj3TI657u3l13GzJjN8E0axM9ZMC@unn@x8lHDJv9@TsdMEPqTfMxcXL0YTTZfhl8z9rsjJ0PbjJa02qqZLTa22d6apuayiUiq8EXZCOjPFH9m1LS6/QCheY4ns4Js8hJ31xl3//Lfu8k13yK6W1m1z@YxatXEZX2cN55pdfxGiXabUoOWJ2se6dpEQzvBYVegD2k0JnkycpUf358vqct2yPJm5ONVClPO7zwv5qrd1dDBNpUbodr/Fqi7L0VFb/BpnSlubNozfLMHYzlzSZiRDGqPsmYwGFBjuMMbUdEY8lfbDIHYJJCe9HwlNJX5y0l6Z9O61wZp2h2MlBDvQ2hH6QHdZ@rzONjkfm6Rpt2XdIzox6jT4Z1@SJS1t3yzIecOHHiuCFlGTQaUa2ywUxgwjPl6CCeRIMeR7p47DsF76Dh7uO84w8znzP/B4@P/)

```py
def FactorECM(N, *, bound = 1 << 8, icurve = 0):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization
    import math, random
    def FactorTrialDiv(x):
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division
        fs = []
        for d in range(2, x + 1):
            if d * d > x:
                break
            while x % d == 0:
                fs.append(d)
                x //= d
        if x != 1:
            fs.append(x)
        return sorted(fs)
    def FermatPRP(n, trials = 32):
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test
        for i in range(trials):
            if pow(random.randint(2, n - 2), n - 1, n) != 1:
                return False
        return True
    def GenPrimes(end):
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes
        composite = [False] * end
        for p in range(2, int(math.sqrt(end) + 3)):
            if composite[p]:
                continue
            for i in range(p * p, end, p):
                composite[i] = True
        for p in range(2, end):
            if not composite[p]:
                yield p
    def GCD(a, b):
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm
        while b != 0:
            a, b = b, a % b
        return a
    def EGCD(a, b):
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm
        ro, r, so, s = a, b, 1, 0
        while r != 0:
            ro, (q, r) = r, divmod(ro, r)
            so, s = s, so - q * s
        return ro, so, (ro - so * a) // b
    def PrimePow(p):
        bound2 = int(math.sqrt(bound) + 1)
        mp = p
        while True:
            mp *= p
            if mp >= bound2:
                return mp // p
    def ModInv(a, n):
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse
        a %= n
        g, s, t = EGCD(a, n)
        if g != 1:
            raise ValueError(a)
        return s % n
    def EcAdd(A, B, X0, Y0, X1, Y1):
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication
        if X0 == X1 and Y0 == Y1:
            # Double
            l = ((3 * X0 ** 2 + A) * ModInv(2 * Y0, N)) % N
            x = (l ** 2 - 2 * X0) % N
            y = (l * (X0 - x) - Y0) % N
        else:
            # Add
            l = ((Y1 - Y0) * ModInv(X1 - X0, N)) % N
            x = (l ** 2 - X0 - X1) % N
            y = (l * (X0 - x) - Y0) % N
        return x, y
    def EcMul(A, B, X, Y, k):
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method
        assert k >= 2, k
        k -= 1
        BX, BY = X, Y
        while k != 0:
            if k & 1:
                X, Y = EcAdd(A, B, X, Y, BX, BY)
            BX, BY = EcAdd(A, B, BX, BY, BX, BY)
            k >>= 1
        return X, Y
    def NextECM(x):
        return FactorECM(x, bound = bound + (1 << 8), icurve = icurve + 1)

    def Main():
        # Main ECM Algorithm    
        
        if N < (1 << 16):
            fs = FactorTrialDiv(N)
            if len(fs) >= 2:
                print('Factors TrialDiv:', fs, flush = True)
            return fs
        
        if FermatPRP(N):
            return [N]
        
        print(f'Curve {icurve:>4},  bound 2^{math.log2(bound):>6.2f}', flush = True)
        
        while True:
            X, Y, A = [random.randrange(N) for i in range(3)]
            B = (Y ** 2 - X ** 3 - A * X) % N
            if 4 * A ** 3 - 27 * B ** 2 == 0:
                continue
            break
        
        for p in GenPrimes(bound):
            k = PrimePow(p)
            try:
                X, Y = EcMul(A, B, X, Y, k)
            except ValueError as ex:
                g = GCD(ex.args[0], N)
                assert g > 1, g
                if g != N:
                    print('Factor ECM:', g, flush = True)
                return sorted(NextECM(g) + NextECM(N // g))
        
        return NextECM(N)
    
    return Main()

def Test():
    import random, time
    bits = 72
    N = random.randrange(1 << (bits - 1), 1 << bits)
    print('N:', N)
    tb = time.time()
    print(N, ':', FactorECM(N))
    print('Time', round(time.time() - tb, 3), 'sec')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test()
```